# What are the open-source projects for virtual assistants with a large community and high customizability?

Tags: github, open-source, home-assistant, assistant

I'm looking for an open-source project related to a home assistant, similar to Amazon's Alexa or Apple's Siri. My objective with this is to use it and contribute to its community. I have found [Rhasspy](https://github.com/rhasspy/rhasspy) and [MycroftAI](https://github.com/MycroftAI/mycroft-core), but I would appreciate advice on other options.

I would like it to be highly customizable to include other projects like [Open-Assistant](https://github.com/LAION-AI/Open-Assistant) and other functions with AI models.